# Regex validating emails with different domains

Tags: regex

could one advise me how to write a regex to validate email address with a different domain eg:

```
emma@pedrex.se
emma@pedrex.de
```

i am currently using the below but unsure how to adjust it:

```
^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$
```

Comment: See http://emailregex.com/

Comment: The book "Mastering Regular Expressions" has an appendix containing a regex to match an email address. It is several *pages* long. The moral - don't use a (single) regex for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer:

```
^.+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+[^.]$
```

Comment: @Toto what would you advise then?

Comment: Try to send an email and test the result.